# Android studio getting admob ads

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

My aplications ads were working very well.
After changing of "max_ad_content_rating", "G" in admob console now I cant see ad.
I am getting

```
[WARNING:cookie_manager.cc(366)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/
```

App doesnot get ads.
mRewardedAd is getting null.
My apps rewarderAds codes as bellow

Launcher

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
        val gameView = initializeForView(CubeKeeper(this), config)
            
        olusturRewardedReklam()
        val layout = RelativeLayout(this)
        layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
   
        setContentView(layout)//En Sona koymalısın


    }
```

Existing ads

```
 fun existRewardedReklam(){
            val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
            RewardedAd.load(this,Rewarded_AD_UNIT_ID,adRequest,object :RewardedAdLoadCallback(){
                override fun onAdLoaded(p0: RewardedAd) {super.onAdLoaded(p0);mRewardedAd = p0}
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0);mRewardedAd=null }
            })
    
        }
```

Calling ads to see on screen

```
override fun showRewardedReklam(callbackMY: CallbackMY){
           if(isOnlinePing()==true){
           runOnUiThread(Runnable {
               run() {
              if (mRewardedAd != null) {
              mRewardedAd!!.show(this, object : OnUserEarnedRewardListener {
                           override fun onUserEarnedReward(p0: RewardItem) {
                               olusturRewardedReklam()                        }
    
                       })
                   } 
    else {
                           existRewardedReklam()
                          
                   }
               }
               mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                   override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
    
                       callbackMY.rewardedReklamSonuclari("reklam basladi")
                   }
    
                   override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
    
                       callbackMY.rewardedReklamSonuclari("reklam baslamadi")
                   }
    
                   override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    
                       callbackMY.rewardedReklamSonuclari("reklam izlemesi bitti")
    
                   }
               }
    
    
           })
    
          }}
```